# Can't get mbstring to work on Amazon linux 2 AMI

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mbstring

I run on Amazon linux 2 AMI, With PHP 7.2.5 and apache

The probleme is: Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding

The initial need is to be able to read an uploaded text file correctly and have its content inserted in DB, knowing that the encodings can be various

The problem i am struggling with is to get mb_convert_encoding working !

i tried:

```
sudo yum install php-mbstring
sudo yum install php7.2-mbstring
```

and all the possible variations and php versions, with a sudo service httpd restart between each attempt, nothing get the function to work.

Any suggestion ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue, strangely when I reboot the instances it did enabled.

**First installed mbstring using this command:**

```
sudo yum install php-mbstring
```

**Then reboot**

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

I don't know why restarting httpd not enough, but its work for me, hopefully will work for you.

Comment: You kid me not, the reboot solution also worked for me. I was mind blown as to why a reboot is needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been searching for this and this exactly was my problem. Restarting EC2 instance fixed it.

Comment: There is no need to shut down the machine. Only need to restart the affected services. If restarting the apache service doesn't work, it's most likely the php-fpm service.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same issue where php exposed via apache httpd would not reflect the updated packages. I could resolve the issue with

```
service php-fpm restart
```

and avoid the system restart

Answer (score 0):

The correct package for PHP7.2 is:

```
sudo yum install php72-mbstring
```

Then a simple HTTPD service restart applies the update:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```